# Solve this using geometric sequence sum: $\sum_{t=1}^{20} (1+x)^{-t}=1000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve $$\sum_{t=1}^{20} (1+x)^{-t}=1000$$

but am having trouble converting the sum of the geometric series to something nice. Could someone give me pointers?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get an explicit answer, but one first step could be setting $y=\frac{1}{1+x}$ just to write things more simply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{t=1}^{20} (1+x)^{-t}=\frac{(x+1)^{20}-1}{x (x+1)^{20}}=1000$$
Instead of thinking about the equation, consider instead that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=(x+1)^{20}-1-1000\,x\, (x+1)^{20}\tag 1$$ As said in comment, facing a polynomial of degree higher than $4$ means that you will need some numerical method.

You must exclude the solution $x=0$ which appears in $(1)$ after and because of the croos-multiplication.

The first derivative
$$f'(x)=-140 (x+1)^{19} (150 x+7)$$ has a first zero at $$x_*=-\frac{7}{150}\quad\implies\quad f(x_0) \sim 17.33$$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a maximum.

Now, still to get an approximation, consider instead function
$$g(x)=\log \left((x+1)^{20}-1\right)-\log \left(1000 x (x+1)^{20}\right)$$ and expand it as a Taylor series around $x=0$
$$g(x)=-\log(50)-\frac{21 }{2}x+\frac{175 }{8}x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Neglecting the higher order terms, at the price of a simple quadatic equation, you have an estimate
$$x_0=\frac{2}{175} \left(21-\sqrt{7 (63+50 \log (50))}\right)=-0.246246$$ while the solution is $-0.239822$.

Now, you have a good starting point and, for example, the iterates of Newton method  will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -0.246246 \\
 1 & -0.239867 \\
 2 & -0.239822 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

This is all ready in the form of a geometric sum (where the ratio would be $\frac{1}{1+x}$. Or you could multiply by $(1+x)^{20}$ and have a geometricsum with ratio $(1+x)$.

Then you can use that it is equal to:

$$ (1+x)^{20}\cdot\sum_{t=1}^{20} (1+x)^{-t} =\sum_{t=1}^{20} (1+x)^{20-t} = \sum_{i=0}^{19} (1+x)^i $$

Them by the known equality for geometric sums:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{19} (1+x)^i = \frac{1-(1+x)^{20}}{1-(1+x)}$$

And you can resolve the equality now:
$$$$
$$ \begin{align*} \frac{1-(1+x)^{20}}{1-(1+x)} = (1+x)^{20}\cdot 1000\end{align*}
$$

the only solution is $x = 0$ as the equation is equivalent to:

$$ 1 = (1+x)^{20}(1000x+1) $$

And we divide in cases if $x > 0 \implies x+1 >1 \implies (x+1)^{20} > 1$ and as the multiplication is equal to 1, we have that $ (1000x+1)$ must be less than 1 but this implies $1000x < 0 \implies x <0$ and that is a contradiction.

Similary if $x < 0$ we have $x+1<1 \implies (x+1)^{20} < 1$ then we have that $1000x+1 >1 \implies 1000x >0 \implies x>0$ so another contradiction.

As we put ourself in every case, this means we proved that there is no solution with $x \neq 0$, and x = 0 is not a solution since the sumatory will be equal to 20 not 1000.

Comment: You seem to have $(1+x)$ twice when you want $(1+x)^i.$

Comment: Great, thanks!- can the last equation you have be solved iteratively (guess for x and re-input it until solved?)

Comment: i dont think that iteratively is the way to go, i added how to solve to find all solutions (there are no others) but this have to be proved not by triyng values